# In Android, how can I find out at runtime the ROM and kernel that the phone is running?

Tags: android, kernel, rom

Basically, I know that a specific kernel  running on a CM10-based ROM has a problem with my app, and I would like to detect that at runtime, and send the user an alert to change kernels. How can I find out the kernel and ROM from within my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

[EDIT]

If Build doesn't give you what you need, try System.getProperty("os.version").  I've tested on 3 devices and it gives the kernel string.  You should be able to get anything that Build does not give you.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not considered to be helpful. Please consider adding some context, or summarising the relevant information from the page.

Comment: Don't think I agree.  One click, and you have everything you need - and better expressed than I could do here.